# Connect-PnPOnline : AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, error, authentication, pnp-powershell

I have this script to connect to a SharePoint online site using username & password:

```
$encpassword = convertto-securestring -String "********" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "****@******.com", $encpassword

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://******.sharepoint.com/ -Credentials $cred
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Connect-PnPOnline : AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a
new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'.
Trace ID: 0e616060-9737-4793-a2df-6dc7e1695000
Correlation ID: 6102bb1c-1b28-4979-994e-83ddb5ddf6e9
Timestamp: 2022-12-07 19:09:26Z
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://****.sharepoint.com/ -Credent ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], MsalUiRequiredException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOn
   line
```

Can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [interactive authentication](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#interactive-for-multi-factor-authentication). This will allow you to complete the multi-factor authentication.

Answer (score 1):

As MFA is enabled for user account, you have below two options while authenticating using `Connect-PnPOnline`:

1. Use `-Interactive` (previously `UseWebLogin`):

   ```
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://******.sharepoint.com/ -Interactive
   ```
2. Use App Password for Office 365:

   You can use **App password** in place of normal password to login easily.

   I am using App Password for authentication in PowerShell as well as SharePoint Designer and it works well.

   [Create an app password for Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-app-password-for-office-365-3e7c860f-bda4-4441-a618-b53953ee1183).

You can find more details in below threads:

1. [Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302388/connect-sposervice-the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-micr/302391#302391)
2. [The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275517/the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-microsoft-account-system/275520#275520)